# Error al modificar un array de strings en mongodb (MEAN stack)

Tags: nodejs, base-de-datos, mongodb, mongoose, backend

Estoy desarrollando una red social con Angular en la parte front y NodeJS, Express y Mongoose en la parte back. La base de datos es, por tanto, MongoDB.
El caso es que estoy teniendo problemas con uno de los apartados de la web. Se trata de un apartado llamado "Eventos", en el que los usuarios pueden ver una lista de todos los eventos (que son partidas online de videojuegos a las que se pueden apuntar) que se muestran de la base de datos. Uno de los parámetros de la colección de eventos es UsuariosApuntados, un array de strings que muestra los usuarios que están apuntados a ese evento. Lógicamente estos eventos se muestran de manera dinámica y en cada uno de ellos se crea también un botón para apuntarse. Al pulsar el botón, se crea un sessionStorage determinado y cuando éste está activo, se hace una llamada al backend para modificar ese evento en concreto. Básicamente se extrae el array de los usuarios apuntados y se le hace un push del nombre del usuario que está en ese momento conectado. de ese modo, simplemente se modifica el array antiguo por el actualizado (el que contiene los nombres anteriores mas el del nuevo usuario que se acaba de apuntar). El problema es que aunque no se produce ningún error, no se modifica el array, sigue siendo el mismo siempre. Lo raro es que si pruebo a modificar cualquier otro parámetro como por ejemplo el nombre del evento, funciona sin problemas.
Dejo por aquí el código del método que cambia el array:

```
agregarUsuario: function (req, res) {
        var idEvento = req.params.id;
        var editar = req.params.UsuariosApuntados;
        var usuariosArray = new Array();
        var editarArray = editar.split(","); //Divido cada nombre por separado
        for (let index = 0; index < editarArray.length; index++) {//Y los añado al array
            usuariosArray.push(editarArray[index]);
        }
        console.log(idEvento);
        console.log(usuariosArray);
        Evento.findByIdAndUpdate(idEvento, { UsuariosApuntados: usuariosArray}, { new: true }, (err, eventoUpdated) => {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(500).send({
            message: "Error al editar."
        })
    }
    if (!eventoUpdated) {
        return res.status(404).send({
            message: "No existe ese evento"
        })
    }
    return res.status(200).send({
        evento: eventoUpdated
    })
```

Como se puede ver, utilizo el método findByIdAndUpdate, introduciendo como parámetros de entrada el id del evento a modificar y la modificación en sí.
Alguien tiene alguna idea de por qué no funciona al modificar un array pero sí al modificar un string?

Comment: Hola Alejando, 
podrías añadir el Schema de `Evento`?
Has probado con esto: `Evento.findByIdAndUpdate(idEvento, { $set: { UsuariosApuntados: usuariosArray } }, ...` ?

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Me he dado cuenta de que se me había olvidado añadir UsuariosApuntados:Array en el schema. Ahora funciona correctamente!